# Why this code runs else statement at last though I have given right inputs?

Tags: java

This program will first ask for the book name. Then it asks for the user's occupation, and will show price. If the desired book is not available it will say
sorry not available and when occupation is not available it will say not identified. The problem is it works randomly, but sometimes displays the error anyway:

[image: example input and output]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class p10 {
    static Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String[] books={"java","python","C"};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter book name:");
        String BookName =a.nextLine();

        if(BookName.toLowerCase().equals(books[0].toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println("you have chosen: "+books[0]+"\n what is your occupation?\n ans: ");
            calculation(BookName);
        }
        if(BookName.toLowerCase().equals(books[1].toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println("you have chosen: "+books[1]+"\n what is your occupation?\n ans: ");
            calculation(BookName);
        }
        if(BookName.toLowerCase().equals(books[2].toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println("you have chosen: "+books[2]+"\n what is your occupation?\n ans: ");
            calculation(BookName);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("sorry !! not available");
        }
    }

    static void calculation(String asd) {
        int Javaprice=700;
        int Cprice=500;
        int Pythonprice=300;
        String name= a.nextLine();
        if(name.toLowerCase().equals("teacher")){
            System.out.println("you are teacher and the  price of the " +asd.toUpperCase()+ " book is : "+Javaprice);
            calc(name,asd);
        }
        if(name.toLowerCase().equals("boss")){
            System.out.println("you are boss and the  price of the " +asd.toUpperCase()+ " book is : "+Cprice);
            calc(name,asd);
        }
        if(name.toLowerCase().equals("student")){
            System.out.println("you are student and the  price of the " +asd.toUpperCase()+ " book is : "+Pythonprice);
            calc(name,asd);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("you are not identified!! can't access to the books!");
        }

    }
    static void calc(String ID,String BOOK){

        System.out.println("\nthanks for shopping "+BOOK+" Book! Come again honorable "+ ID);
    }
}
```